# dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_bz2)

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I am using Python3.6 on CentOS linux and have created virtual environment using venv. I installed matplotlib using pip install matplotlib and it completed successfully. Now when I am trying to import matplotlib in python command line it is producing Import Error:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/yogeshs/Python3.6VE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from . import cbook
  File "/home/yogeshs/Python3.6VE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import bz2
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_bz2)
>>>
```

I read almost all the answers on similar issues on Stackoverflow and tried to follow the steps but I am unable to to resolve this problem. Can somebody please guide me through this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Such things mostly happen when there is a mismatch between python version and build package. Do you have several python versions installed?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes... I have got several versions of Python installed by several others on this server. Further, some of them are installed systemwide and some of them are user specific... And that is the reason I am working in a virtual environment, to avoid conflict.

Comment: Still I suppose the error you're seeing stems from such conflict. Hard to say from the outside.